# Running telethon on pythonanywhere

Tags: python, console, telegram, pythonanywhere, telethon

try to run a basic scripts that adds members to a telegram group over pythoneverywhere server. I installed the main package which is telethon in the server. but i am getting the error in the image below. what am i not doing right? 
error message is given below

```
21:02 ~/Villians TV/Villians5/TeleGram-Scraper-master $ python3 villians5.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "villians5.py", line 17, in <module>
    client.connect()
  File "/home/somti13/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telethon/sync.py", line 39, in syncified
    return loop.run_until_complete(coro)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 608, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/somti13/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telethon/client/telegrambaseclient.py", line 472, in connect
    if not await self._sender.connect(self._connection(
  File "/home/somti13/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telethon/network/mtprotosender.py", line 125, in connect
    await self._connect()
  File "/home/somti13/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telethon/network/mtprotosender.py", line 250, in _connect
    raise ConnectionError('Connection to Telegram failed {} time(s)'.format(self._retries))
ConnectionError: Connection to Telegram failed 5 time(s)
```

Comment: First check if script works on your local computer. With `pythoneverywhere` can be other problem - it blocks access to many portals to stop spamers or scrapers. `pythoneverywhere` has somewhere `whitelist` with portals which you can access - but I'm not sure if you can access these portals using free account.

Comment: on PythonAnywhere [whitelist](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/whitelist/) I see `api.telegram.org` (IP: `149.154.167.220`) and `core.telegram.org` (IP: `149.154.167.99`) but in [telethon code](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/blob/master/telethon/client/telegrambaseclient.py#L21) I found IP: `149.154.167.51` - so `PythonAnywhere` can blocks it.

Comment: `client.session.set_dc(dc_id, ip, port)` will let you change where Telethon will connect to (if you do this before starting the client). Note that if your account is from a different datacenter, Telethon will need to reconnect to it, which may be blocked. Note also this should only be done for new sessions.

Comment: is there a link to a tutorial video i can check out to get this done?

Comment: or is there a way i can reach you on any social media for guidance

Answer (score 1):

The mtproto connection type for telegram does not work for free accounts on PythonAnywhere. Only http(s) connections out of PythonAnywhere will work for free accounts.